# Is there a simple way to write physical constants?

Tags: physical-constants

I don't want to write

```
UnitConvert[Quantity["MagneticConstant"]]
```

all the time in my expressions.

I can't write

```
μ[0] = UnitConvert[Quantity["MagneticConstant"]]
```

because Mathematica doesn't treat subscripted variables in the same way as simple ones. Neither can I write

```
mu_0 = UnitConvert[Quantity["MagneticConstant"]]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would use `mu0`.

Comment: Maybe try inline free-form input, Insert > Inline Free-form input and just type "magnetic constant" or "hbar" or "speed of light" or whatever you want, exit the little box and it should automatically figure out what constant you mean.

Comment: The Notation package allows you to define subscripted variables.

Comment: Mathematica will accept `μ0` as an identifier.

Comment: `$Post` might be useful for you as well.

Answer (score 4):

Subscripts can be added with Ctrl - (Cmd - on Mac), or via the Basic Math Assistant palette. Mathematica will then recognise $\mu_0$ as a variable.

The same can be achieved with `Subscript[μ,0]=UnitConvert[Quantity["MagneticConstant"]]` so you can easily create an array of constants with subscripts.